# Signal assignment in VHDL? Critical Warnings

Tags: signals, vhdl

there are some critical warnings, but i dont know where exactly they are or even how to get rid of them...
The warnings say that there are syntax errors in some lines, but i just dont see them :(
I marked the lines with --ERR at the end of the line

By the way, is the definition of the RAM block ok?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;


Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;
library UNIMACRO;
use unimacro.Vcomponents.all;

entity Buffer_BRAM is
  generic( ADDR : integer :=32);
  Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
         rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
         data_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
         data_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end Buffer_BRAM;

architecture Behavioral of Buffer_BRAM is

  component BRAM_32_16K
    generic(
      PTR1 : integer := 0;
      PTR2 : integer := 1024;
      PTR3 : integer := 2048;
      PTR4 : integer := 4096
    );
    PORT(
      clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rsta : IN STD_LOGIC;
      wea : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
      addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      dina : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);

      clkb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rstb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      web : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
      addrb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      dinb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      doutb : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
    );

  end COMPONENT;

  signal input1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := "10101100010100111010110001010011";
  signal input2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := "10101100010100111010110001010011";

  signal ptr_read, ptr_write : std_logic_vector(ADDR-1 downto 0) := (others =>'0');

  signal WEA, WEB : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :=(others=>'1');
  signal dinb, doutb, dina, douta : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal rsta, rstb :std_logic := '0' ;
  signal num1, num2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

  begin process(clka, rsta, ptr_write)
    dina := input1;                     --ERR
    ptr_write <= ptr_write + 4;
  end

  begin process(clkb, rstb, ptr_write)
    dinb := input2;                     --ERR
    ptr_write <= ptr_write + 4;
  end

  begin process(clk, rst)               --ERR
    doutb <= ptr_read;                  --ERR
    num2 <= doutb;
    ptr_read <= ptr_read - 1; 
  end

end Behavioral                          --ERR
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your signals and your components *before* the `architecture begin`.  Try this:

```
architecture Behavioral of Buffer_BRAM is

  component BRAM_32_16K
    generic(
      PTR1 : integer := 0;
      PTR2 : integer := 1024;
      PTR3 : integer := 2048;
      PTR4 : integer := 4096
    );
    PORT(
      clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rsta : IN STD_LOGIC;
      wea : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
      addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      dina : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);

      clkb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rstb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      web : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
      addrb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      dinb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
      doutb : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
    );

  end COMPONENT;

  signal input1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := "10101100010100111010110001010011";
  signal input2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := "10101100010100111010110001010011";

  signal ptr_read, ptr_write : std_logic_vector(ADDR-1 downto 0) := (others =>'0');

  signal WEA, WEB : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :=(others=>'1');
  signal dinb, doutb, dina, douta : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal rsta, rstb :std_logic := '0' ;
  signal num1, num2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

  begin -- ONLY ONE BEGIN IS USED, BEGINS THE ARCHITECTURE

  process(clka, rsta, ptr_write)
  begin  -- OTHER BEGINS ARE FOR YOUR PROCESSES
    dina := input1;                     --ERR
    ptr_write <= ptr_write + 4;
  end

  process(clkb, rstb, ptr_write)
  begin  -- OTHER BEGINS ARE FOR YOUR PROCESSES
    dinb := input2;                     --ERR
    ptr_write <= ptr_write + 4;
  end

  process(clk, rst)               --ERR
  begin  -- OTHER BEGINS ARE FOR YOUR PROCESSES
    doutb <= ptr_read;                  --ERR
    num2 <= doutb;
    ptr_read <= ptr_read - 1; 
  end

end Behavioral                          --ERR
```

As a side note, I don't think any of these processes will do what you intend them to do.  None of them are clocked!  They should look something like this:

```
  process(clk)               --ERR
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      doutb <= ptr_read;                  --ERR
      num2 <= doutb;
      ptr_read <= ptr_read - 1; 
    end if;
  end
```

As another side note, you cannot do math on your signals without including another package file.  You should be including `numeric_std` in the top of your file.

Found more stuff wrong.  Don't use the `:=` assignment operator here.  This is meant only for variables and for signal initialization.  This will cause a compile error.